# Process builder Queue bug

Tags: community, workflow, process-builder, configuration

I am trying to send notification to previous owner whenever current owner is changed on Lead.I have created Previous owner email field on lead.

I have a process flow which has criteria whenever owner is changed immediate update action will be performed.Please find the formula update below:

```
IF(AND(LEFT(PRIORVALUE([Lead].OwnerId), 3) = "00G"), PRIORVALUE([Lead].Owner:Queue.Email ), PRIORVALUE([Lead].Owner:User.Email ))
```

But whenever I change the queue owner to user ,I am getting flow error

> The flow failed to access the value because it hasn't been set or
>   assigned

Answer (score 0):

You may get this issue if the email id is empty.

Please ensure that the email ID is not null, before executing the actions.

You've to add entry criteria before executing the actions.

Comment: Yes .Email Id is available for both queue and user